# Starting Parpool in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, parallel-processing, local, matlabpool

I tried starting `parpool` in `MATLAB 2015b`. Command as follows,

```
parpool('local',3);
```

This command should allocate 3 workers. Whereas I received an error stating failure to start `parpool`. The error message as follows,

```
 Error using parpool (line 94)
 Failed to start a parallel pool. (For information in addition to 
 the causing error, validate the profile 'local' in the Cluster Profile
 Manager.)
```

A similar query was posted in (https://nl.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/196549-failed-to-start-a-parallel-pool-in-matlab2015a). I followed the same procedure, to validate the local profile as per the suggestions.

Using `distcomp.feature( 'LocalUseMpiexec', false);` or `distcomp.feature( 'LocalUseMpiexec', true)` in `startup.m` didn't create any improvement. Also when attempting to validate `local` profile still gives error message as follows,

```
VALIDATION DETAILS
Profile: local
Scheduler Type: Local

Stage: Cluster connection test (parcluster)
Status: Passed
Description:Validation Passed
Command Line Output:(none)
Error Report:(none)
Debug Log:(none)

Stage: Job test (createJob)
Status: Failed
Description:The job errored or did not reach state finished.
Command Line Output:
Failed to determine if job 24 belongs to this cluster because: Unable to 
read file 'C:\Users\varad001\AppData\Roaming\MathWorks\MATLAB 
\local_cluster_jobs\R2015b\Job24.in.mat'. No such file or directory..

Error Report:(none)
Debug Log:(none)

Stage: SPMD job test (createCommunicatingJob)
Status: Failed
Description:The job errored or did not reach state finished.
Command Line Output: 
Failed to determine if job 25 belongs to this cluster because: Unable to 
read file 'C:\Users\varad001\AppData\Roaming\MathWorks\MATLAB   
\local_cluster_jobs\R2015b\Job25.in.mat'. No such file or directory..

Error Report:(none)
Debug Log:(none)

Stage: Pool job test (createCommunicatingJob)
Status: Skipped
Description:Validation skipped due to previous failure.
Command Line Output:(none)
Error Report:(none)
Debug Log:(none)

Stage: Parallel pool test (parpool)
Status: Skipped
Description:Validation skipped due to previous failure.
Command Line Output:(none)
Error Report:(none)
Debug Log:(none)
```

I am receiving these error only in my cluster machine. But launching `parpool` in my standalone PC is working perfectly. Is there a way to rectify this issue?

Comment: `Unable to 
read file 'C:\Users\varad001\AppData\Roaming\MathWorks\MATLAB 
\local_cluster_jobs\R2015b\Job24.in.mat'` Says your error. Does MATLAB has access to read/write on there?

Comment: That's true. Actually there is no such directory or file at that path as the error states. I think `MATLAB` has access to `read/write` at that path.

Comment: That thing looks like something MATLAB would go and write after the test, for later open it and read it. IF it does not exist, the most likely thing is that MATLAB can not write on it.   `.\AppData\...` is generally a folder that a program will not be able to access, so check again if MATLAB can indeed create stuff there.

Comment: Yes. Matlab has `read/write` control in that folder. It did write `.\AppData\...\MATLAB\local_cluster_jobs\R2015\Job23.in.mat` and has also read `.\AppData\...\MATLAB\local_cluster_jobs\R2015\Job23.jobout.mat`. While I couldn't see Job 24, 25 as the error file states.